# Need a solution for loading 1000 + images in a row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically i have a page that has 1000+ images and it takes for ever to load. what would be the best method to use to only load the first 10 images then when a user scrolls down or clicks a button the next 10 loads.

Thanks in advance

```
$large = 'large';
$q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE status = ? AND slot = ? LIMIT 0, 5");
$q->bindParam(1, $live);
$q->bindParam(2, $large);
$q->execute();
if($q->rowCount() > 0){
    echo '<div style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 1020px; border: 2px solid #428bca"></div>';
    while($r = $q->fetch()){
    $web = $r['website_url'];
    $img = $r['image_url'];
    {
    echo '
    <a target="_blank" href="'.$web.'"><img style="margin-left: -4px" src="'.$img.'" height="150" width="150" onmouseout="shrink2(this);" onmouseover="expand2(this);"/></a>
    ';
    }
}
}
```

its That x 10,000

Thats just one query obviously i cant enter all 1000 + queries

Comment: [**http://goo.gl/gdplTE**](http://goo.gl/gdplTE), there ya go

Comment: @adeneo That was soo Cool and Thanks

Comment: @Lashane ive already views that one didnt work for me trying Nicks one now

Comment: "SOME INFO: its not in a database, its all in one file already written." you'll have to fix that first. There isn't much you can do to prevent those images from loading by the time you can execute javascript. Possibly output an array of image paths to javascript instead of writing <img> tags to the page.

Comment: @KevinB could you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use.  Easy to set up too :)

http://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/

Example page: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html

Comment: should i apply the class name to all the queries??

Comment: That would probably be easiest.  It'll load in any images that are in view straight away anyway.

Comment: it isnt working for me :( any more suggestions